# Imageless 3d content boxes - is this possible?

Tags: css

I am attempting to recreate these two content boxes stacked ontop of one another without images - https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiINW.png is this possible or would an image have to be used for the lower box?

[image]

Comment: You should accept Ana's answer over mine. It's way more thorough and has better compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be reproduced really well, with minimal markup in... well, almost any browser, really. I did two versions, the **HTML** for both is the same.

```
<div class='box box1'>
    <div class='box1-content'>Box 1 content goes here.</div>
</div>
<div class='box box2'>Box 2 content goes here.</div>
```

The **first version** uses **CSS 3D transforms** and should work in Safari, Chrome, Firefox and IE10. Opera and IE9 (and older) don't support 3D transforms, so it won't work for those.

## [*demo*](http://dabblet.com/gist/4570533)

Relevant **CSS**:

```
html { background: linear-gradient(#165284, #3672a4) no-repeat; }
.box { position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 90%; }
.box1-content, .box2 { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 1%; min-height: 16em; }
.box1 { z-index: 2; margin-bottom:  1.6em; box-shadow: 0 1.4em 1em -1em; }
.box1:before, .box1:after {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: .5em; right: .6em; bottom: .5em; left: .6em; 
    border-radius: .35em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2em;
    content: '';
}
.box1:before { transform: skewX(5deg); }
.box1:after { transform: skewX(-5deg); }
.box1-content {
    border-radius: 0 0 .5em .5em;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #e14f00, #f88d00);
}
.box2 { z-index: 1; background: gainsboro; perspective: 32em; }
.box2:before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 5em;
    transform: rotateX(45deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 100% 0;
    background: linear-gradient(dimgrey, silver);
    content: '';
}
```

---

The **second version** is the **better compatibility** one and should work fully (shadows + emulate 3D effect) in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE9+ and Opera. The 3D effect should also be emulated in IE8, even if the shadows won't be there.

## [*demo*](http://dabblet.com/gist/4570702)

Relevant **CSS**:

```
html {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#165284',
            endColorstr='#3672a4', GradientType=0); /* fallback for IE9/8 */
    background: linear-gradient(#165284, #3672a4) no-repeat;
}
.box { position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 90%; }
.box1-content, .box2 { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 1%; min-height: 16em; }
.box1 {
    z-index: 2;
    margin-bottom:  1.6em;
    box-shadow: 0 1.4em 1em -1em; /* not supported in IE8 */
}
.box1:before, .box1:after {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: .5em; right: .6em; bottom: .5em; left: .6em; 
    border-radius: .35em; /* not supported in IE8 */
    box-shadow: 0 0 2em; /* not supported in IE8 */
    content: '';
}
.box1:before { transform: skewX(5deg); } /* not supported in IE8 */
.box1:after { transform: skewX(-5deg); } /* not supported in IE8 */
.box1-content {
    border-radius: 0 0 .5em .5em;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e14f00',
            endColorstr='#f88d00', GradientType=1); /* fallback for IE9/8 */
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #e14f00, #f88d00);
}
.box2 { z-index: 1; background: gainsboro; }
.box2:before {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%; right: 0; left: 0;
    border: solid 4em transparent;
    border-bottom: solid 5em silver;
    content: '';
}
```

You could go overboard and try to emulate shadows for IE8/ 3D effect and shadows for IE7 using additional elements instead of pseudo-elements and applying matrix transform/ shadow filters on those, but I think it's not worth it.

Answer (score 2):

It took a while, but I think I managed (sort of) what you want. The only thing that can't be done is the 'fancy' shadow at the sides.

Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/Lkp7G/2/)

### Notes:

- Only works in Chrome and Safari!
- Read through [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_perspective.asp) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_perspective-origin.asp) to understand `perspective` and `perspective-origin` respectively.
- Tweaks will be needed when applying to your own website! Especially the positioning.
- A negative `z-index` is required on the shadow box. This might interfere with your own site. I know it is not the most practical and handy method, but it's the most straightforward and effective one.

Comment: wow, i never expected this would be possible in css. It isn't going to work in all browsers though.

Comment: @Ragnagord The beauty of CSS3. :)